# ethtool config precedence on physical interface or bond?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, bonding

If I have a physical interface that (for example) has large-receive-offload configured to 'off' and that interface is part of a mode4 bond group that has large-receive-offload set to 'on' which will take precedence? In this configuration is large-receive-offload actually on or off?

bond0 config

```
[me@host1 ~]$ ethtool -k bond0 | grep large
large-receive-offload: on
```

eth0 config

```
[me@host1 ~]$ ethtool -k eth0 | grep large
large-receive-offload: off
```

eth0 interface config (slave to bond)

```
[me@host1 ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
USERCTL="no"
MASTER="bond0"
SLAVE="yes"
BOOTPROTO="none"
ONBOOT="yes
```

bond config

```
[me@host1 ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE="bond0"
USERCTL="no"
TYPE="Bond"
BOOTPROTO="none"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="10.0.0.100"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4 updelay=0 lacp_rate=1 ad_select=0 "
```

Answer (score 1):

> Not all of the tx offloading features are copied from slaves to the
> upper device like bonds and vlans. Bond devices inherit some of the tx
> offloading features from slaves. Vlan devices inherit some of the tx
> offloading features from bond.

Source, [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/750503) Red Hat article.